# Sql query to get data based on only month and day

Tags: mysql

I have the following table with the following data:

```
tbl_tasks
===================
tid - autonumber int pk
desc - text
due_date - datetime

data
===================
1
Description 1
2014-09-15 01:15:00

2
Description 2
2014-09-15 01:15:30

3
Description 3
2014-09-16 01:15:00

4
Description 4
2014-09-17 01:15:30

5
Description 5
2014-09-18 01:15:00

6
Description 6
2014-09-19 01:15:30
```

How would i be able to query this table and only get the data for the 09-15?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `MONTH()` and `DAY()` functions which parse out just those segments of the date.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_tasks WHERE MONTH(due_date) = '09' AND DAY(due_date) = '15'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_tasks WHERE due_date BETWEEN '2014-09-15 00:00:00' AND '2014-09-16 00:00:00'
```

Comment: Unless I misunderstand the subject of his question, he is concerned with *not* using year.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something, but I think:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_tasks WHERE due_date = "2014-09-15";
```